# How to design a editor field in asp.net mvc to display only the textbox?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

As i have not created a field for the current date in a database table, and not also in model class also, but i want to display only the view of that field?

```
<div class="editor-label">
  @Html.Label("Date")
</div>                     
<div class="editor-field">
  //here is the problem what to do??
??
</div>
```

Comment: When the field is available in model then only you can use the html helpers like `EditorFor` or `ValidationMessageFor` or any html helper that has the suffix `For`. Hence you must use the html helpers like `@Html.TextBox` for your situation.

Comment: Unclear what your wanting to so. Why would you create a form control and associated validation message when there is nothing to edit and nothing to validate. If you just want to display the current date use `<div>@DateTime.Now</div>` (and format it with `.ToString()` if you want)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just want to show a field you can add 
input tag give it a name and id,
Or you can use the razor syntax to add a text field !!
if you want to use that field for datepicker then use Jquery DatePicker
This Link might help you 
[Jquery DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBox("SomeName","SomeValue")
```